# how to maven build the project with artifact id or group id via batch script?

Tags: java, maven, powershell, batch-file

Need to write batch script to build the sequence of maven projects.

I feel that building the projects from project folders is quite difficult because the folders name can be editable.

For eg: In my system, project folder name may be "ProjectA" but in others it may be like "ProjA". So, how come the possibility to find the particular project pom for  maven build.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `execute`? If you are in the project's directory you can do `mvn clean install` without even knowing its artifactId. I'm wondering if you mean that developers might have clone the projects from git under different names and so you don't know how to cd into the correct directories as you don't know the directory names. If so your best bet is to standardise on a clone script so everyone clones the repos into the same dir structure. You could try to scan the filesystem for a stable string like artifactId but that would be brittle. But I am just guessing on this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ryan. yeah I'm looking for the kind of scanning approach to find the project names. I don't want to manually "cd" for each and every project. For the directory, I'm getting the path as user input via script but need to find the workaround for finding project name.